# Using react and webpack: use the non-minified dev environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, mobiscroll

I am using webpack to test a new plugin of mobiscroll as I am getting an error and needed to make sure it wasn't my set up.

However now I get the error that implies (at least from searching) that I am using browserify.

```
react-with-addons.min.js:16 
    Uncaught Error: 
      Minified exception occurred; use the non-minified dev environment for the full error message and additional helpful warnings.
```

I have put it up on github for people to checkout and test:

https://github.com/jamiehutber/mobiscroll-webpack

**things I have done already**

```
set NODE_ENV=development //set in my npm start script and also set manually before running npm start
```

How can i stop this error?

Answer (score 2):

Youre adding react-dom in the `index.html`

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.34/browser.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-with-addons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

And you're also including it with Webpack in index.js. Remove these from `index.html`

Comment: Hadn't thought of this :) Thank you, the reason for adding in the html is because the mobiscroll needs it to be global. I will have to remove it from webpack.

Comment: You can still make it global via Webpack (which i think you should do). Im not entirely familar with the library but in your entry (I think it was index.js) you could do `window.[globalName] = require('react-dom');`  This is a better approach because you dont have JS resources included in html, and it sets you up for code splitting the third-party libraries into its own vendor bundle.

Comment: I will try this knowing it is meant to work. As this was how I originally tried it. Its es2015 as well. But that shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: In an unrelated SO post someone mentioned using the [expose loader](https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader)